# How do I display a list of assets with the entries they are related to?

Tags: entries, assets, relations, assetfilemodel

Given a list of assets, for each asset, how do I display a list of entries that relate to this asset? So, for instance, if asset A is selected as asset in entries 1 and 2, I want a list to be displayed like this:

- Asset A:

  - Used in entry 1
  - Used in entry 2
- Asset B:

  - Used in ... etc.

With this ...

```
{% set content = craft.entries.section('content').find() %}
{% set usedFotos = craft.assets.relatedTo(content).find() | group('id') %}
```

... I can see if certain assets are used, but now I want to see what entr(y/ies) they belong to.

Comment: Paul, did the answer I provided help you with your problem?

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try yet, will do tonight. Was hoping for a 'one-query solution' ;)

Comment: Yeah I also hoped to find a solution with less DB queries, but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have to query a new ElementCriteriaModel for each asset in your loop and use the [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter to filter the relevant "content" entries.

You could use the `targetElement` property with the `relatedTo` parameter to be more spezific on that relation. But you should be fine using the `element` property or the short syntax [`relatedTo(element)`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param), if you don't do any (reverse) relations (e.g. with an entries field as an [asset meta field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets#asset-meta-fields)).

Tested this on an install with 400 images and yes, you want to wrap it in `cache` tags!

```
{% set content = craft.entries.section('content').find() %}
{% set usedFotos = craft.assets.relatedTo(content).order('filename').find() %}

{# Loop throught the array of assets #}
{% for usedFoto in usedFotos %}

    <h2>{{ usedFoto.filename }}</h2>
    <ul>

        {# Loop throught entries related to this asset #}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(usedFoto).order('title') %}
            <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```