# Order by related field title

Tags: entries, relations, ordering

I have a series of talks that have speakers as a related entry.

I'm looking for a way to order the talks by the last name of the speaker (the last name is the title of the speaker channel).

Comment: Still looking for an answer, Steven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to loop through all the speaker (ordered by lastName) that are related to the talks (the speaker entry is the `targetElement`). Then use one `craft.entries` (ElementCriteriaModel) for each loop to get the talk entry.

See [this Q/A](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2010/125) for a comparable problem.