# Twig in External jQuery

Tags: templating

I'm a little bit new to Craft, but it's already my favorite CMS, even after 8 years or so in Wordpress.

Here's what I need to do. I have integrated a preloader into my site, using preload.js, and I need to know if there is a way to utilize Twig within my JavaScript files.

Essentially, preload.js gets all of the assets to preload from a load Manifest, which is created with JSON. I got this working properly as an inline script, simply pulling the sources of all my assets, based on [this question.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-do-i-display-a-list-of-assets-with-the-entries-they-are-related-to) What I need to know is, is there a way to use these Twig tags inside of an external JavaScript file? I know that there is in liquid, but I'd like to get this working here as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your javascript file in the templates folder. E.g. place a file called `external.js` in the folder `craft/templates/includes/`. Then include it like this `<script src="/includes/external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I don't know if this is an official way to do it, but it works.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It says that it doesn't recognize the curly brackets as part of the code.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you need to escape certain parts of the javascript code? Have a look at [this](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#working-with-automatic-escaping).